# Output of Get-Azure VM is di

Tags: powershell, azure, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script that takes an Azure account as input, and outputs a table with each subscription as a column along with count sizes by VM type, states, etc.

```
   $VMs = Get-AzureVM | where {$_.Status -eq "StoppedVM"} | select Name, ServiceName, Status
$VMStoppedCnt = $VMs.Count
```

When I run the ps1 file in powershell or in powershell ISE, my $VM.Count values are as expected.  However, when it runs as a scheduled task all values = 0 (it still outputs the table).

Example output when run via powershell :

```
Subscription    D2  D4  D14 A1  A2  A3  A7  G4  TotalVMs    TotalKnownVMs   NonStandardVMs  Running Stopped StoppedDeallocated
```

Repro Labs  4   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   13  9   4   9   4

Example output when run through task scheduler calling powershell:

```
Subscription    D2  D4  D14 A1  A2  A3  A7  G4  TotalVMs    TotalKnownVMs   NonStandardVMs  Running Stopped StoppedDeallocated
```

Repro Labs  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520303/get-azure-vm-detail-by-powershell) issue, or could be something with account/script permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh My !!! I am answering this question for 5th time. Windows task scheduler won't exactly run your powershell file, However it will show task as completed as status. Azure powershell scheduling cant be done using windows task scheduler because it won't actually connect to Azure console due to lack of credentials/certificate or something.
Go for Azure runbook model using portal. use same code. I bet you can't do it using windows task scheduler.

a. Most imp- Go to ASSET tab and add proper windows powershell credentials (simply you can use username and password, the same you use to login to azure portal).

b. Add your code in the runbook. Suppose your powershell automation credential name is autoaccount and your subscription name is xxx. In this case the workflow will be-

```
workflow autoaccount 
{
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName “xxx”
inlineScript
{
*YOUR CODE HERE*
}
}
```

c. After this you can schedule your runbook as per your need.

Hope this one will help you-

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/25/introducing-the-azure-automation-script-converter/ http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-create-runbook-from-samples/

Thanks.